# How to uninstall a application through powershell which is not a Microsoft product

Tags: powershell

I want to uninstall an application through powershell scripting which is not a Microsoft product

I have tried with the below code but then it says "you cannot call a method on a null valued expression". This was because it couldn't point to that respective software.

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Software_Name*" }
$app.Uninstall()
```

And when I tried with `Get-RemoteProgram` command, it is listing out only the Microsoft softwares.

How to uninstall other softwares?

Comment: the recommended solution is to search the uninstall section of the 32bit & 64bit Software registry areas and use the uninstall string found there. a net search shows many scripts for just exactly that.

Comment: a tip I can give you : don't use Win32_Product since this WMI class is broken and can ruin other installed software on your machine (since this class forces a consistency check on all MSI packages and may trigger a repair on them)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to find the GUID of the application in the registry in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and uninstall it using MsiExec:

```
Start-Process -FilePath MsiExec -ArgumentList '/quiet /uninstall {109A5A16-E09E-4B82-A784-D1780F1190D6}' -Wait
```

The above example uninstalls the `Windows Firewall Configuration Provider`.